# retain only specific rows psycopg2

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a table containing jobs like this

```
id   owner          collaborator    privilege 
90  "919886297050"  "919886212378"  "read"
90  "919886297050"  "919886297052"  "read"
88  "919886297050"  "919886212378"  "read"
88  "919886297050"  "919886297052"  "read"
```

primary key is a composite of id, owner and collaborator
I want to pass in details of only the collaborators i want to retain. For example, if my collaborator  = "919886212378" it means I want to delete the row for "919886297052" and keep the row for "919886212378"

Is there a way to do this in one query / execution instead of fetching the details separately and then performing the delete after filtering the missing values?

EDIT: My use case might have new collaborators added and old ones deleted. However, my input will just have a set of chosen collaborators so I will need to cross check with the old list, retain existing, add new and delete missing collaborators.

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE collaborator NOT IN ("919886212378", "id ..")
```

does the delete for the specific case you mentioned. But I don't know
how you get these id's. You give too little information regarding your exact case.
If you can get these id's by a query, you could make it a subquery like:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE collaborator NOT IN (SELECT ... FROM ...)
```

Comment: Please add more explanation.

Comment: I get the ids from a request. I guess I wasn't clear in the question but this solution only deletes the missing values. if new collaborators are added and some old ones are deleted, then how do we do it?

Comment: Can you be specific with an example ?

Answer (score 0):

Comparing the old and new collaborator lists in python kind of did the trick for me

```
    original_list = ["C1","C2","C3","C4"] // result from query
    updated_list= ["C1","C6","C7"] // list obtained from request


    # compute the differences   
    to_be_added  = set(updated_list).difference(set(original_list) )
    to_be_deleted  = set(original_list).difference(set(updated_list) )
```

Then I use an insert and delete statement within a transaction using the above two lists  to make an update.